# How can a combined SQL find books in a library available for borrowing?

Tags: sql, firebird

Database of a brand new library in the university:

```
create table "Book" (
  "BookCode" varchar(10) primary key, 
  "BookTitle" varchar(10) not null
);
insert into "Book"("BookCode", "BookTitle") 
  values('Book1', 'Book one');
insert into "Book"("BookCode", "BookTitle") 
  values('Book2', 'Book two');
insert into "Book"("BookCode", "BookTitle") 
  values('Book3', 'Book three')
    
create table "BorrowBook" (
  "ID" bigint generated by default as identity primary key,
  "StudentID" varchar(10) not null,
  "BookCode" varchar(10) not null,
  "BorrowDate" date , "ReturnDate" date);
insert into "BorrowBook"("StudentID", "BookCode", "BorrowDate", "ReturnDate")
  values('S1', 'B1', '2021-1-1', '2021-1-3');
insert into "BorrowBook"("StudentID", "BookCode", "BorrowDate", "ReturnDate")
  values('S1', 'B1', '2021-1-4', '2021-1-6');
insert into "BorrowBook"("StudentID", "BookCode", "BorrowDate", "ReturnDate")
  values('S1', 'B1', '2021-1-7', null);
insert into "BorrowBook"("StudentID", "BookCode", "BorrowDate", "ReturnDate")
  values('S2', 'B2', '2021-1-1', '2021-1-3');
insert into "BorrowBook"("StudentID", "BookCode", "BorrowDate", "ReturnDate")
  values('S2', 'B2', '2021-1-4', '2021-1-6');
```

I could get only BookCode unavailable for borrowing:

```
select distinct "BookCode"
from "BorrowBook"
where "BorrowDate" is not null and "ReturnDate" is null
```

How can a combined SQL find BookCode, B2 & B3, available for borrowing (and B1 unavailable for borrowing)?

Comment: Your schema query is wrong. You have the BookCode as `Book1` in the `Book` table, but `B1` in BorrowBook.

Comment: I would say that the schema is wrong in general. Table "Book" itself should contain a field for the current state of the book such as "borrowed", "lost", "in repair", "available". In this case the query becomes trivial.

Comment: Libraries usualyl have several "instances" of the same (by title/content) book. Like a standard textbook should have as many copies as there are students and then some for reserve. So, the table "Book" - describing "class types" rather than "object instances" should not have "instance status" field. Granted, there has to be a correct `FOREIGN KEY` from `BorrowBook` to `Book` (book descriptions) or maybe to one more table `BookItems`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mr. SchmitzIT. You have different book codes in the two tables. As you posted, you will not be able to join on `"BookCode"`. So assuming `"BookCode"` is the same in the two tables.

**Also strictly answering your question**:

> How can a combined SQL find BookCode, B2 & B3, available for borrowing
> (and B1 unavailable for borrowing)?

This means you only get a list of books either available or not, not knowing which is which. This would be the answer:

```sql
select distinct b."BookCode"/*change to * to see*/ 
from "BorrowBook" a, "Book" b
where 
a."BookCode"(+) = b."BookCode" and
(
  "ReturnDate" is null or a."BookCode" not in 
  (
    select "BookCode" 
    from "BorrowBook" 
    where "ReturnDate" is null
  )
);
```

This, will provide the same output using `distinct`, simplifying the query, but with a larger dataset (look at it using `*`):

```sql
"ReturnDate" is null or "ReturnDate" is not null
```

But again, **strictly answering the question**.

---

Assuming you do need to know which is which:

```sql
-- add ===> a.*, <==== instead of the distinct, to see all
select distinct b."BookCode", case when ("ReturnDate" is null and "BorrowDate" is not null) then 'Not available' else 'Available' end
from "BorrowBook" a, "Book" b
where 
a."BookCode"(+) = b."BookCode" and
(
  "ReturnDate" is null or 
  a."BookCode" not in 
  (
    select "BookCode" 
    from "BorrowBook" 
    where "ReturnDate" is null
  )
);
```

Comment: B1 is not available since it has not been returned.

Comment: Oh, I see now...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Great job on expanding your answer :) One minor thing though is that you should stick with the ANSI standard of creating explicit JOINS (I.e. `FROM Tablea INNER JOIN Tableb ON Tablea.Col = Tableb.Col`, rather than FROM TableA, TableB WHERE TableA.Col = TableB.Col`. The latter syntax is outdated.

Comment: Sorry for I gave wrong sample data, the correct one should be:

`insert into "Book"("BookCode", "BookTitle") 
  values('B1', 'Book one');`
`insert into "Book"("BookCode", "BookTitle") 
  values('B2', 'Book two');`
`insert into "Book"("BookCode", "BookTitle") 
  values('B3', 'Book three'`

Comment: It's kind of ok as it was too. Since `B3` was never borrowed, it is logical it should not appear in the `"BorrowBook"` table. That's your original scenario.
But do edit your original post. It's ok to do that. You can add an "EDIT" disclaimer or something for fairness.

Comment: Given your use of  `a."BookCode"(+) = b."BookCode"`, I assume this answer was written with Oracle in mind instead of Firebird (or standard SQL for that matter), right?

Comment: Oh, yes, the little tag. I didn't see it. Yes, Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SQL Server solution.

We first grab the very latest dates from the BorrowBook table, as those will tell us whether or not the book currently is available. This is done by creating a Common Table Expression sorted by BorrowDate Descending.

We left join that to books, in order to find books that have not yet been borrowed (Book 3), and then check the availability:

```
WITH MaxDate AS (
  SELECT BookCode, BorrowDate, ReturnDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BookCode ORDER BY BorrowDate DESC) AS rn FROM BorrowBook
)
SELECT 
  book.BookCode
  , IIF(BorrowDate IS NULL, 'Available', IIF((ReturnDate IS NULL) OR (ReturnDate >= GETDATE()), 'Not Available', 'Available'))
     AS Availibility
FROM
  Book AS book
  LEFT JOIN MaxDate bb ON book.BookCode = bb.BookCode AND rn = 1
```

The resultset:

```
BookCode    Availibility
B1  Not Available
B2  Available
B3  Available
```

SQLFiddle:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1c1fc/7